# PHP command + value? how?

Tags: php

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 B
with the GPIO pins i'm controlling my led strip.
i made something in PHP.
Buttons works fine but i can't figure out how to get a input text box string.

This is my script :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['button11'])) {
    exec('pigs p 18' + INPUT TEXTBOX OR JSCOLOR RED OUTPUT);
    exec('pigs p 23' + INPUT TEXTBOX OR JSCOLOR GRN OUTPUT);
    exec('pigs p 24' + INPUT TEXTBOX OR JSCOLOR BLU OUTPUT);
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
  <input name="red" id="red" size="5">
  <input name="grn" id="grn" size="5">
  <input name="blu" id="blu" size="5">
</form>
<p> Of kies een kleur: <input class="color" id="myColor" onchange="
    document.getElementById('red').value = this.color.rgb[0]*255;
    document.getElementById('grn').value = this.color.rgb[1]*255;
    document.getElementById('blu').value = this.color.rgb[2]*255;
    <title>Sherin's RGB Ledstrip</title>
    </head>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="button11" style="background-color:#000000; color: #ffffff;" >
            Activeer je bovenstaande gekozen kleur
        </button>
    </p>
    </form>
```

I know that INPUT TEXTBOX wont work. but how do i get the value of that textbox and paste it after the command??
I used a color picker, name : JSCOLOR.
I want the R string, G string, B string after the 3 commands.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Move your red, blue and green fields inside the second form. Then, after submit, you'll be able to access them with `$_POST['red'], $_POST['blue'], ...`

Comment: Also, you may consider using [escapeshellarg function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to safely use the user input with you command call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a proper form.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['form'])) {
    $form = $_POST['form'];

    if ($form == 'my_form') {
        $input = $_POST['my_value']; // read the value from the textbox
    }
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="my_value" value="foo" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="my_form" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move these:

```
<input name="red" id="red" size="5">
<input name="grn" id="grn" size="5">
<input name="blu" id="blu" size="5">
```

Down to the form with the button in it. That way their values will be in the POST variables.

Frankly, its difficult to tell exactly what values you need submitted based on your code structure. Just remember any inputs you want submitted via form needs to be within the form's tags (not in another form or outside of it)